# Given a jQuery mouseover event where you get e for event. How can I get the width of the item that triggered it?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery mouseover event like so:

```
$('#outer').mouseover(function() {
   console.log(     e.target.width()    );
});
```

I'm trying the above but that's not working. Ideas on how I can get the width of the element that fired the mouseover?

Thanks

Comment: passed as argument `$('#outer').mouseover(function(e) { `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#outer').mouseover(function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).width());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that it always outputs 0... It's a svg path element, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can you try instead:     `console.log( e.target.width, e.target.getAttribute("width"), e.target.offsetWidth );` and see if all are 0

Comment: That outputs: undefined null 0

Comment: If I log just $(e.target), I do get the element: [<path fill="#1a4496" stroke="#ffffff" d="M94.99899251104148,94.99598619357182L54.49797795010788,165.14974356341412A80.99999999999999,80.99999999999999,0,0,0,176.00202165795957,94.99598619357181Z" style="stroke-width: 2px; " stroke-width="2" transform="  "></path>]

Comment: Try `console.log( e.target.getTotalLength() )`. `Path` element will not have any standard width property or method as normal html elements have. Note that this will fail if the `e.target` is not a `path` element because normal elements don't have `getTotalLength` method

Comment: Thanks that did provide a number. Strangely, The SVG is in a div that is only 190px wide and the # it returned was 501.319458 so that didn't work

Comment: Yeah I looked through all the methods of `SVGPathElement` and that's all I could get :(. All width/height properties are set to 0 in the element for some reason. You can type this in google chrome console to get list of methods: `SVGPathElement.prototype;`

Comment: Ok finally got it, WOW that was painful :) ----    var pathWidth = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   var pathHeight = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height;

Comment: be aware that `e.target` is not supported by all browsers

Comment: @KrisIvanov, it is because... I just explained it in a comment to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to pass the event object, you could also do:

```
$('#outer').mouseover(function () { 
    console.log($(this).width()); 
});
```

Comment: Tried that it errors with: 6492Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: this is better solution since some browsers use different ways of getting event target, like `e.srcElement`, etc

Comment: btw, try warping the svg in another control like `div` and use that for width, seen it work before

Comment: the svg is in a div but in the svg are several path elements.

Comment: can you post your `svg` element, or some simplified version of it to be able to work with

Comment: 1. `this` always refers to the #outer element, not necessarily the element that first triggered the event. 2. `e.target` is always `e.target` in any browser as `e` is the jQuery normalized event object, not browser event object (which is `e.originalEvent`)